# Is a question on "what system-agnostic gifts that aren't books are there?" appropriate?

Tags: discussion

Do you think a question on "what system-agnotic-non-book-buying geeky gifts" is appropriate? My family wants to get me cool RPG geeky stuff for Christmas and I'm coming up short on ideas.

I'm a little concerned that it might be seen as advertising products, which is not the aim. The aim is to get a list of system agnostic coolness to use at the table.

I imagine such a question would become community wiki.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No, but not for why you're thinking.**

Lists... are not so good. Lists that are certainly going to be out of date, or horribly broad are doubleplusungood.

If you can phrase it as a game-recommendation question such that it can actually *have* an answer by fulfilling a specific need, great. But "give me list of stuff!" not so much, no.

Comment: A good idea would be "how could I create such a list", but I'm not sure it would be a RPG question anymore.

Comment: Thanks, Brian. I felt as much. I can't think of a better wording for it. I might have to blog it or something to get some ideas.

Comment: There are RPG forums where you could ask this, too.

Comment: Cheers, Jonathan, that's a good call. After checking here, I did just that! :)